# How can i re-render all my components on a click function in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, reload

is it possible to re-render all my vue components on a click function 
i have read about`vm.$forceUpdate()` but it dose not effect all child components.
is there any other way?
thank you all

Comment: 1. What do you mean by all? 2. Why do you need to do that? 3. By "reload" do you mean "re-render"?

Comment: Might help if your share some code and how your project is set up.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do that ? Your components should get automatically updated on any data / prop changes. If that's not the case in your code (and if it is your problem indeed), I would first try to look into your data to see if they behave like you expect.

Comment: i know my components should update automatically but its seems its not because after re-rendering everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You probably not doing things in vue way if you need that kind of functionality, but quick hack which might help you to achieve what you want is to refresh whole page via javascript. So inside click function insert this:

```
location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was my function was not working because i wrote it in  mounted, and i had to reload or re-render my page to make that function work
after i change my function to updated the problem was solved
[vue.js  Lifecycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)